# cfinclude paths will not recursively resolve in Application.cfc?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, application.cfc

This is CF11.

I have a collection of dependencies that I must `cfinclude` at the top of every CFM and CFC we run. It is a single `cfinclude` that recursively includes other files. This has worked on every page load for many years; mostly legacy CFM pages, and some newer CFCs. However, I've recently tried to do this from within an `Application.cfc`, and while it resolves the top-most include, it fails to resolve the children includes. I get the typical `cfinclude` relative-path error message:

```
... Note: If you wish to use an absolute template path (for example, template="/mypath/index.cfm") with 
CFINCLUDE, you must create a mapping for the path using the ColdFusion Administrator. Or, you can use 
per-application settings to specify mappings specific to this application by specifying a mappings 
struct to THIS.mappings in Application.cfc. ...
```

From the CFC itself (called from the browser with URL `x/index.cfm`), I have:

```
getBaseTemplatePath() = x/index.cfm
getCurrentTemplatePath() = x/Application.cfc
expandPath("./") = x
```

And from the top-most include:

```
getBaseTemplatePath() = x/index.cfm
getCurrentTemplatePath() = y/TheInclude.cfm
expandPath("./") = x
```

Other CFCs in this application - those siblings of `Application.cfc` that `cfinclude` the same file - produce the same path expansions, but also successfully resolve the child includes. Am I doing something wrong, is this a bug in `Application.cfc`, or ...?

Comment: Maybe it’s time to refactor. This sounds like a terrible thing to do, especially with modern CFML. If that’s not an option, I would add mappings specify absolute paths to the includes.

Comment: Where in the `Application.cfc` would one put `cfinclude` tags?

Comment: filed cf bug CF-4207025

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug and has been verified by Adobe.

Bug report CF-4207025.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the content of what is inside those includes.

Check this:
https://helpx.adobe.com/in/coldfusion/cfml-reference/application-cfc-reference/application-variables.html

Comment: You should include some of the details you thing are relevant. A link only answer is likely to get deleted

Comment: But I told what it is, that is something inside in those includes. In the link have a full list of what is not allowed. Simple as that.